# What happens to the holes in the skull where teeth were developing?

Tags: human-biology, teeth

In Skeptics.SE, a question regarding the skulls of children arose. Depicting a scary skull where the permenent teeth are "hidden" inside the jaws and the milk teeth are in the their place.

After all milk teeth fall out, and the permanent teeth "rise", do the holes left by them filled up, or do we go around with holes in our jaws?

[The question on Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9541/is-this-scary-looking-image-about-child-teeth-development-accurate)

The picture:

[image: picture]

Comment: Permanent teeth have much larger and stronger [cemented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cementum) roots.

Comment: Jaw development is very prominent during the growth of a child. There are no holes that remain in the jaw after the emergence of all the permanent teeth. Permanent teeth are not fully formed and hidden. They develop while milk teeth, meanwhile do the temporary job.

Comment: When the tooth falls out you can see a little adult teeth behind it after a couple of weeks the adult teeth will grow and move to the front and the adult teeth will not fall out so look after your teeth for your life

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bone growth continues in the human body for quite awhile after permanent teeth come in. Generally, the complete closure of all growth plates doesn't occur until the mid 20s.

As the top and bottom primary teeth come in, the empty space left behind is gradually filled by growth of the maxilla and mandible, respectively. During the time period when teeth are actively coming in, teeth can displace into the empty space left by other permanent teeth that are no longer there, resulting in crooked teeth.

Answer (score 7):

This is a skull of a child of around 5 plus years; based on the eruption status and is an example of  classic development and eruption pattern of of the teeth at that age. everyone goes through it. It probably looks scary to persons unfamiliar with normal anatomy and because the outer cortical plate has been removed to show the developing tooth germs. This is out of a anatomy museum meant for medical or dental students.
At no point of time during the eruption is a cavity left behind. As the tooth erupts the base of the crypt (cavity) gets filled up.